# Increase and decrease row value by 1 in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hi I have a MySQL database table "points" the user can click a button and a point should be removed from their account, the button they pressed has an ID of another user, therefore their account must increase by one.

I have it working in jQuery and checked the varibles/posts in Firebug, and it does send the correct data, such as:

```
userid= 1 
posterid = 4
```

I think the problem is with my PHP page:

```
<?php


include ('../functions.php');

$userid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$posterid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['poster_id']);

if (loggedin()) 
{
include ('../connection.php');
$query1 = "UPDATE `points` SET `points` = `points` - 1 WHERE `userID` = '$userid'";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);


$query2 = "UPDATE `points` SET `points` = `points` + 1 WHERE `userID` = '$posterid'";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);


if ($result1 && result2)
{
    echo "Successful";  
    return 1;
}
else
{

    echo mysql_error();
    return 0;   
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: you forgot to mention the problem itself

Comment: oh yeh sorry, well it doesnt increase or decrease the row...I tested them in mysql and they work fine.

Comment: mysql_error() may help to find the problem

Comment: Question: what results do you get? "Successful" / 1 ?

Comment: @Elliot How can you see an error if it's AJAX call?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Two queries to increase/decrease field value are not necessary:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = 1
```

is a perfectly valid query as you can see next:

```
mysql> describe points;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| points | int(11) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into points VALUES (1,0),(2,0);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> select * from points;
+-----+--------+
| uid | points |
+-----+--------+
|   1 |      0 |
|   2 |      0 |
+-----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> update points set points = points+1 where uid = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.27 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from points;
+-----+--------+
| uid | points |
+-----+--------+
|   1 |      1 |
|   2 |      0 |
+-----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Having that tested, are you sure you get into your `if (loggedin())` clause?

I have to agree with `KM`, would be nice to see output of `echo $query1;` or `echo $query2;`

Comment: UPDATE xyz, `SET Column=Column+n WHERE ...` is very standard SQL, I'll bet that for some reason the OPs sql string is not being constructed the way they want, hence the recommendations to display $query1 and $query2.  I'll bet the problem becomes obvious after seeing their contents.

Comment: Hi thanks, the echo of each query is just the same as the query I wrote above.

Comment: Fixed it , just re-wrote it out again and seemed to work haha
thanks

Comment: It works for me, except that when decreasing, can't get the value to reach 0 (it stops at 1 and further decreases have no effect). The field is an INT **NOT** defined as 'not-null'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the example query, tested by me and it is working 100%

```
$query="UPDATE table_name SET `hit_count`=(`hit_count`+1) WHERE `id` = '1'";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be sure to read previous answers before posting. As that is essentially the same as the accepted answer. Best not to disturb ancient threads unless the response adds something significant that is missing from previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
update table_name set  col_name=col_name+1   where sqId = 12
```

But if your `col_name` by default value is null or empty it never works, so make sure that `col_name` default value is `0` or any integer value.

Answer (score 0):

```
update 'tablename' set 'columnname1'='columnname1' + 1 where 'columnname2'='value';
```

eg: `update students set englishmarks=englishmarks + 1 where name='Rahul';`

Edit:(Explanation)
"UPDATE" keyword is used to update a vaule in the table. Here I am updating a value in the table "students". "SET" keyword updating the english marks by 1(just like in C language, how we increase the value of an integer, i=i+1) and condidtion is given where name is "Rahul".

So englishmarks of Rahul are incremented by 1

Answer (score 0):

In laravel Migration do:

```
\DB::statement('SELECT @pos:=0;');
\DB::statement('UPDATE users SET company_id = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) WHERE `id` = '1';');
```

If want to change all records, remove the WHERE `id` = '1'

It will insert number increment to your records like:

```
+-----+------------+
|  id | company_id |
+-----+------------+
|   1 |      1     |
|  12 |      2     |
|  23 |      3     |
+-----+------------+
```